# Active user account after fill form

Tags: 8

Hi all my client wants like
Dont activate user accounts instantly
Upon vendor or Client submitting the form, send an email to Administrator notifying them
send an email to vendor / client to confirm the registration.
on drupal 8

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that functionality by setting the config variable:

```
USER_REGISTER_VISITORS_ADMINISTRATIVE_APPROVAL
```

e.g: `$config->set('register', USER_REGISTER_VISITORS_ADMINISTRATIVE_APPROVAL)->save();`

For example, via the admin user config page at:

*/admin/config/people/accounts*

setting *"Who can register accounts?"* to *"Visitors, but administrator approval is required"*